# Issues with PrintStub() Function's ouput

Tags: c++

Hopefully you can kind of see where Im going with this. FICA at 7.65%, FedTax at 22 or 28% depending on the amount made, and state tax at 12%. I have to make all of these functions come to an output of:

```
 Name earned $645.00

 FICA $xxx.xx

 Fed $xxx.xx

 State $xxx.xx

 Net Pay $xxx.xx
```

So I believe mathematically I am there, its just setting up for success is where Iam genuinely stuck.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int hourRate, hourWork, otHours, pay, FICA, state, fed, netpay;

void Pause()
{ string junk, extraNewLine;
cin.ignore();
cout << "Press Enter to continue ... ";
getline(cin, junk);
}

void GetPay(){
    pay = (hourRate * hourWork) + (otHours * (hourRate * 1.5));
    cout << pay;
}

void GetHrs(){
    cout << " Hours worked? ";
    cin >> hourWork;
    if (hourWork > 40){
        otHours = hourWork - 40;
        hourWork - otHours;
    }
    else {
        otHours = 0;
    }
}

void GetRate(){
    cout << "Hourly Rate? ";
    cin >> hourRate;
}

void CalcFCIA(){
    FICA = pay *.0765;
    cout << FICA;
}

void CalcFedTax(){
    if (pay > 1500){
        fed =  pay * .28;
    }
    else {
        fed = pay * .22;
    }
}
void CalcStateTax(){
    state = pay * .12;
    cout << state;
}

void PrintStub(){
        cout << "FICA $" + FICA;
        cout << "Fed $" + fed;
        cout << "State $" + state;
        netpay = pay - (FICA + fed + state);
        cout << "Net Pay" + netpay;

}

int main()
{
    string name;

    cout << "Employee name? ";
    cin >> name;

    GetRate();
    GetHrs();
    PrintStub();



Pause();
}
```

My output is not displaying any integers. I am only getting:
FICA $Fed $State $Net Pay

Comment: Just change `+` tp `<<` with `cout`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Not Im only getting 0 as my final integer.

Comment: So there must be some other bug in your code. Just use your debugger to detect where exactly that is. That's not an issue you delegate to the Stack Overflow community.

Comment: Im not getting anything in my debug output. It has to be something with the placement/calling of my functions.

Comment: Step through your code line by line with your debugger and observe the variable values changing.

Comment: Just fyi, when you store a number with a decimal portion as an int the decimal part is truncated. So your desired output is not going to have decimal points. All your variables are ints. `hourWork - otHours;` does nothing also, and you're not calling CalcFCIA(), etc.

Comment: you never call any of those functions, ClacFedTax, CalcStateTax,...

Comment: I have now and still getting 0 value in results.

Comment: @AustinStephens I get that. I planned on making it pretty after I get the functions to work.

Answer (score 2):

You don't appear to be calling any of the Calc functions. Each of them will have to be called in order to have any effect.

Also, it will likely help you follow the logic to write functions that return values rather than operating on global variables -- it makes the transformations you're doing on the data much more explicit. For example, you could use functions like:

```
int CalcFICA(int pay){
    return pay * .0765;
}
```

Comment: I cant figure out where to call the Calc functions. I tried in PrintStub() and still returning 0 value. And how would I return value in the calc functions.

Comment: @TylerKanz Personally, I'd call them between the Get functions and the PrintStub function so that your overall control logic looks like "get inputs, calculate values, output values", but anywhere that's both after the Get functions and before you use the relevant variables in the PrintStub function would work.

Comment: Thats where the Calc functions are. I dont think I can call them there. And did you mean:  void CalcFICA(int pay){}

Comment: Still cant seem to figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: @TylerKanz Calling GetPay and then the Calc functions in main, between the calls to the Get functions and the PrintStub function and changing the + operators to << operators in the cout lines in PrintStub (e.g. `cout << "FICA $" << FICA`) works on my end.